# Julia Set Rendering on JPanel in Java - colours only one Pixel

Tags: java, swing, math, awt, paintcomponent

I am attempting to write a program that renders the Mandelbrot set, and then a Julia Set for a complex number in another panel, when the user clicks on a point on the Mandelbrot set panel.

However, my Julia's set rendering code for some reason does not work. It appears to only colour the top-left most pixel, and I cannot figure out why this might me. I don't know if the maths is wrong in the rendering method, or if the colouring is the issue. Any pointers or a solution would be fantastic - been scratching my head over this for awhile.

If anyone would find this easier to solve by having all of the code, please let me know - thanks.

Here is the code for just the Julia's Set Panel, everything else has been omitted.

```
  class juliaPanel extends JPanel {

        ComplexNumber fixedNumber = new ComplexNumber(0,0);
        double newReal, newImaginary, oldReal, oldImaginary;

        public void setFixedNumber(ComplexNumber fixedNumberIn) {
            fixedNumber = fixedNumberIn;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            newReal = 0;
            newImaginary = 0;
            int i;
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    for (i=0; i< iterationsToDo; i++) {
                        oldReal = newReal;
                        oldImaginary = newImaginary;
                        newReal = oldReal * oldReal - oldImaginary * oldImaginary + fixedNumber.getReal();
                        newImaginary = 2 * oldReal * oldImaginary + fixedNumber.getImaginary();
                        if((newReal * newReal + newImaginary * newImaginary) > 4) break;
                    }
                    if(i == 255){
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }else{
                         g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(i/100.0F,1F,1F));
                    }
                    g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is you're not resetting newReal and newImaginary to 0 in your second loop.

Comment: and how are you setting height width iterationsToDo?

Comment: Hi Weblog - are you suggesting I should move the two statements setting those variables equal to zero into the iterationsToDo loop? Many thanks for the quick response.

Comment: `i/100.0F` doesn't seem correct to me, since the argument needs to be between 0 and 1 inclusive.  I suspect you want `(float) i / iterationsToDo`.

Comment: Hi gpasch - that is a user defined variable stored in a variable higher up the hierarchy of the program. The test number I am using is 100. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi VRG - I have made the change you suggested to the colour line, yet still in debugging I can see that only on the first iteration is a different colour given (255,15,0 in my test case) and then every other iteration is given as  (255,0,0). Many thanks.

Comment: No, I am suggesting you move those statements to the x/width loop.

Comment: Hi Weblog -sorry misread. I have made that change but still nothing - exactly the same result as before, just the first pixel being coloured.

Comment: Welbog - I tell a lie. It now colours the entire panel an orangey colour or red dependant on the complex number passed in. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all above for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting the inner loop over `i`, i.e., after `x` and `y` have changed to the next pixel, you need to set the initial complex number according to this pixel, something like

```
newReal = minReal + x*deltaReal;
newImag = maxImag - y*deltaImag;
```

where the `min` and `max` are `-2.0` and `2.0` and the `delta` are `4.0/width` and `4.0/height` or the minimum of both to get 1:1 aspect ratio.

Comment: Hi LutzL - I am guessing this instead of setting them to 0 in the same place, as suggested by Welbog in the comments above? Thanks for the reply and I will give it a go now

Comment: LutzL, this appears to work! Renders an image that (I think is) this Julia Set of the ComplexNumber passed in. Many thanks for your help. Have marked the answer as correct. Thanks again.